# Как узнать размер развернутого вьюпорта браузера в JS?

Tags: javascript, viewport

Всем здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли с помощью чистого JS, вычислить размер вьюпорта в развернутом виде (когда браузер развернут на весь экран), в момент, когда браузер развернут **НЕ** на весь экран.

Comment: в смысле узнать размер экрана?

Comment: alert(window.screen.availWidth);
alert(window.screen.availHeight);

Comment: Нет, не размер экрана, а именно внутренней части браузера, без скролла, панели меню и т.п.

Comment: window.screen.availWidth - в Хроме, и Лисе показывает размер вьюпорта тот, который на данный момент есть у браузера. Т.е., если он на пол экрана, то и показывает половину от максимально возможного. Как-то так, надеюсь, понятно объяснил?!

Comment: не понимаю, чем конкретно вас не устраивает window.screen.availWidth/availHeight. вот пример https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_screen_all по-моему он именно то что вам нужно и показывает, независимо ведь от размеров окна браузера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**screen.availWidth** и **screen.availHeight** возвращают именно те значения, которые вам нужны - доступную часть экрана, исключая элементы браузера (в отличии от **screen.width** и **screen.height**, которые возвращают размер всего экрана).

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, Вы правы! Но у меня возникает другая проблема. **availHeight** у меня показывает какую-то постоянную высоту (728px), даже, если я у браузера отключаю/включаю панель закладок, панель меню.

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы результат совпадал с **window.innerHeight** в развернутом состоянии браузера, но **innerHeight** зависит от текущего размера окна браузера, поэтому он не подходит. Есть ли "золотая середина" между этими свойствами?

Comment: Разве в фуллскрине панель закладок должна отображаться? У меня в этом режиме отображается только скроллбар (его ширина вычитается из ширины экрана, но высота не затрагивается). В полноэкранном режиме браузер может отображать различные свои элементы поверх страницы, но эти вещи не учитываются. screen.availHeight возвращает именно доступную часть экрана, а не обозреваемую.

Comment: window.innerHeight и screen.availHeight не должны отличаться в полноэкранном режиме. Я не знаю, какие вы панели включаете. В хроме никаких панелей в этом режиме нет. Вот установил сейчас фаерфокс чтобы проверить. Нажимаю F11 и та же самая картина - чистая страница и полоса прокрутки сбоку, больше ничего.

Comment: Ну в любом случае, если там что-то и можно включить, то это скорее всего float-элемент. А если нет, попробуйте тогда самостоятельно рассчитать размеры, используя window.outerWidth и window.outerHeight.

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под "доступной частью экрана"? Вся остальная часть экрана, кроме той, которую занимает панель задач Windows? Если я убираю панель задач Windows, то availHeight у меня в FF и IE10 = 768px (с панелью задач 728px), а вот в Хроме остается стабильно 728px в обоих случаях.  И еще, для уточнения, под "браузер в развернутом виде" я понимаю развернутое состояние браузера с видимыми адресной строкой, панелью закладок и видимыми значками свернуть, свернуть в окно, закрыть.

Comment: не то, что по F11 вызывается

Comment: Значит я вас не правильно понял и мой ответ не совсем по теме.

Comment: outerWidth в Firefox и IE10 = 1382px (больше чем разрешение экрана у меня) outerHeight = 744px, в Хроме outerWidth=availWidth=1366 и outerHeight=availHeight=728  Разрешение моего экрана 1366 х 768.

Comment: outer возвращает размеры окна с его элементами, inner только внутреннюю часть. если вычесть inner из outer, получите размеры элементов браузера. почему у вас outer больше размеров экрана, я не знаю :(

Comment: наверное я этот ответ удалю в ближайшем времени, раз речь идёт не о фуллскрине.

Comment: зная размеры элементов браузера, вы можете вычесть их из размеров экрана чтобы узнать размеры рабочей области при развёрнутом окне, но эти значения будут неточными, поскольку вы не знаете ничего об элементах интерфейса операционной системы пользователя.

Comment: дело в том, что понятие "развёрнутое окно" не универсально. это обычное окно, с другими размерами и другой позицией. это совсем не тоже самое, что "полноэкранное окно".

Comment: в JS нет такого API, чтобы опрашивать оконный менеджер и узнавать параметры развёрнутого окна.

Comment: Да, я понял. Спасибо Вам.